# Reversing a python string - why does this work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python for data analytics and I'm a little stumped on why the following code works  -

```
newstring = ''

oldstring = 'Newton'

for char in oldstring:

   newstring = char + newstring

print(newstring)
```

I know of easier ways to reverse strings (.reversed and ::-1) but I'm not sure I understand the logic behind why the above code reverses the string.

Comment: ... Because it prepends each character in turn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop takes each character of 'Newton' and appends that character to the front of 'newstring'

So:

### loop 1

Char = N
newstring = N

### loop 2

Char = E
Newstring = EN

### loop 3

Char = w
newstring = WEN

etc

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I wasn't getting that it was adding it to the beginning of the new string, makes more sense when I see it written out like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are prepending each character from `oldstring` to `newstring`:

```
newstring = ''
oldstring = 'Newton'

for char in oldstring:
    # first iteration: char = 'N'
    # second iteration: char = 'e'

    newstring += char

    # first iteration: newstring = '' + 'N' -> newstring = 'N'
    # second iteration: newstring = 'e' + 'N' -> newstring = 'eN'

    # ... It is the same for the whole loop ...
```

Comment: Thanks, like I told the other guy for some reason I wasn't realizing that each character would be going to the beginning of the new string.